# In Xcode how to suppress "incomplete implementation"?(inheritance)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, inheritance

I have a method which is implemented in its super method. And when I run my program. It works fine. How do I suppress this warning? By the way, both methods are in '.m' file.

The code is like this:

ClassA.m

```
@interface ClassA()
- (void)method;
@end
```

ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA : ClassB
@end
```

ClassB.m

```
@interface ClassB()
@end
@implementation ClassB
- (void)method
{
}
```

And it works OK when I call method in ClassA

Comment: post some code, without it, your question is unclear

Comment: @MichałZygar, it is rather clear. I have a method in a class and the implementation is in its super class.

Comment: i don't think so. It seems like you built some strange structure there. Anyway. Why do you have a method implemented in super class and declared in derived class? Why don't you put the declaration of this method in superclass header file? Then you can call this method directly from derived class.

Comment: @MichałZygar,thanks for explaining this for me. I added the code.

Comment: maybe a Protocol is a better solution!

Comment: What I want is to have the implementation code in the super class B so that I can have multiple classes inherit from that class B and I do not need to write that code several times. And it is all working fine, except that it generates a warning.

Comment: @meccan. I forgot to @..

Comment: ok under this circumstances a class is the better solution.

Comment: user1214321, if you want this to work this way, go with the second example in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got it completly wrong. Popular construction is to have:

ClassB.h

```
@interface ClassB
- (void)method;
@end
```

ClassB.m

```
@interface ClassB()
@end
@implementation ClassB
- (void)method
{
    //do nothing or even assert false
}
@end
```

ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA : ClassB
@end
```

ClassA.m

```
@interface ClassA()
@end
@implementation ClassA
- (void)method
{
    //do your stuff here
}
@end
```

And that's called method overriding. But if I correctly understand what you are trying to achieve you should have:

ClassB.h

```
@interface ClassB
- (void)method;
@end
```

ClassB.m

```
@interface ClassB()
@end
@implementation ClassB
- (void)method
{
    //do your stuff here
}
@end
```

ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA : ClassB
@end
```

And there is no need to mess up with ClassA, and you can call

```
ClassA *o=[[ClassA alloc ] init];
[o method];
```

Then the `method` is available in classA thanks to inheritance from ClassB.

Comment: You mean that there is no way to put the method in '.m' file? But my app is actually working. Why is that?

Comment: Well, it is working, because the method is defined there(although not delcared). But if you put a method declaration in .m file, this declaration will only be visible in this .m file and hidden(not declared) anywhere else. So what you have now is: The method from classB is called, but it is not declared(it's like a lucky shot). The method in classA is declared but not defined(does not have implementation), so it's missing for the compiler.

Comment: sometimes it is cannot be do for example when you when Class A has dynamic properties, which would you like to use.

Answer (score 2):

You could always implement the method anyway, and call the super method -

```
-(void)doMyThing {

    [super doMyThing];

    // do nothing

}
```

Comment: But it's defined in .m file. Compiler does not see it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've declared the method in the .h file when you shouldn't have?  Or perhaps the @end is missing from the .h file.

You aren't giving us much to go on. Can we see your full code from the .h and .m?

---

Having read your code sample, try the following:

ClassA.h

```
@interface ClassA : ClassB  
//ClassB inherits from Class A, so we define 'method' in Class B
//ClassA knows about 'method' by inheritance from class B,
//so 'method' doesn't need to be defined here.

//doStuff will be the method that calls 'method'
- (void)doStuff;
@end
```

ClassA.m

```
@interface ClassA
@end

@implementation ClassA
- (void)doStuff
{
   //Call 'Method'       
  [self method];
}
@end
```

ClassB.h

```
@interface ClassB  
//Define 'method' which will be inherited by ClassA 
- (void)method;
@end
```

ClassB.m

```
@interface ClassB
@end

@implementation ClassB
- (void)method
{
   //'method' does it's thing       
  NSLog(@"Method has been Called");
}
@end
```